# merge sorted arrays with their origin annotated

Tags: awk

Given two sorted arrays (the following is an example), I want to merge them into an array along with the info on where they are from.

```
x1[1]=10
x1[2]=20
x1[3]=30

x2[1]=15
x2[2]=25
x2[3]=35
```

The output should be something like this.

```
x[1]=10
x[2]=15
x[3]=20
x[4]=25
x[5]=30
x[6]=35
a[1]=1
a[2]=2
a[3]=1
a[4]=2
a[5]=1
a[6]=2
```

How can I make an awk function to do this job efficiently?

```
function f(r, a, x1, x2) {
# r output merge array
# a an annotation array indicating whether an element at a given index is from x1 or x2
# x1,x2 input sorted arrays
  ...
}
```

Comment: the sample arrays you've shown are valid in both `bash` and `awk`; can you confirm that you're looking for a purely `awk` solution? in other words, you're *not* looking to use `awk` to merge some `bash` arrays, right?

Comment: please update the question with your `awk` version (eg, the output from `awk --version`)

Comment: are both input arrays *guaranteed* to be indexed from `1` to `n` with no gaps in the numbering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that both `awk` arrays start at index `1` and don't contain gaps:

```bash
awk '
    BEGIN {
        x1[1]=10; x1[2]=20; x1[3]=30
        x2[1]=15; x2[2]=25; x2[3]=35

        n = f(r,a,x1,x2)

        for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
            print "x[" i "]=" r[i]

        for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
            print "a[" i "]=" a[i]
    }
    function f(r,a,x1,x2,    i,i1,i2) {
        delete r
        delete a
        i = 0
        i1 = i2 = 1
        while ( (i1 in x1) && (i2 in x2) )
            if ( x1[i1] <= x2[i2] ) {
                a[++i] = 1
                r[i] = x1[i1++]
            } else {
                a[++i] = 2
                r[i] = x2[i2++]
            }
        while ( i1 in x1 ) {
            a[++i] = 1
            r[i] = x1[i1++]
        }
        while ( i2 in x2 ) {
            a[++i] = 2
            r[i] = x2[i2++]
        }
        return i
    }
'
```

Output:

```
x[1]=10
x[2]=15
x[3]=20
x[4]=25
x[5]=30
x[6]=35
a[1]=1
a[2]=2
a[3]=1
a[4]=2
a[5]=1
a[6]=2
```